# Use Azure Cloud Service for License Server

Tags: azure, licensing

I want to build a license server (or service with DB) hosted by Azure for my .Net desktop application. For example, we'll give our customer a serial key to activate the application, and any time the application is started, it will send a request to Azure to validate the serial number.

The application in question would check for a matched license file on the server, then download this license file to the customer's PC. Of course, it will be also used to check license and update.

I am totally new to Azure, do I need a VM or just build a cloud service?
How does it technically work, could somebody give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This completely depends on what you are looking for. Azure has different products for different use cases.

What kind of program is your "license server"? Is this a .NET Console application? Your best bet would be to use a "cloud service" and build a "worker role" around your application. Worker roles are really console apps hosted on a VM by Microsoft and allows you to preinstall software on the VM itself. You do not get any direct control over the OS (more explained here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/plankytronixx/archive/2012/06/08/the-difference-between-azure-vms-and-azure-vm-role.aspx

If you need fine grained control over the license server (e.g. you need to install a full SQL Server on it - you will be required to either deploy a virtual machine with SQL or deploy your database to SQL Azure and use a worker role.

The Microsoft documentation can be a bit off for newcomers to the platform but reading is key! Good luck